# SQL (Redshift) "starts with"

Tags: sql, query-optimization, amazon-redshift

I have one table "prefixes" containing path prefixes, e.g. `a/b/c/`, and another table "keys" containing absolute paths, e.g. `a/b/c/foo.txt`.

I'm joining the latter against the former on (conceptually) "key.value starts with prefix.value".

Initially I tried

```
keys.value like prefixes.value || '%'
```

...but that was problematic for prefixes containing characters that are meaningful to the "like" operator, e.g. `_`, `%`, etc.

I settled on:

```
substring(keys.value, length(prefixes.value)) = prefixes.value
```

...but it's considerably slower.  Other posts suggest a regexp_replace to escape the special characters in the prefix, followed by using the like operator with a trailing `%`, but I can't imagine that's an improvement performance-wise given the regexp_replace().

Is there a cleaner/quicker/better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you modify the tables involved? Ideally I'd add a column to the "keys" table containing a just the prefix part of the key, hopefully both tables are distributed on this column, which then makes for a simple and efficient join on the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the comparison using string functions:

```
from prefixes f join
     keys k
     on p.value = left(k.value, length(p.value))
```

You can adapt the `like` using an escape character (that is not in the keys):

```
from prefixes f join
     keys k
     on k.value like replace(replace(p.value, '_', '#_'), '%', '#%') escape '#'
```

If neither of these are faster, you might be able to use both conditions and still get decent performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `position(prefixes.value in keys.value)=1`